# Selenium grid - Error forwarding the new session cannot find

Tags: linux, selenium, centos7, selenium-grid

I recently installed a selenium grid environment for development testing. However, we are facing the error below:

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --no-sandbox], binary: , prefs: {plugins.always_open_pdf_externally: true}, w3c: false}, loggingPrefs: org.openqa.selenium.logging..., version: 88.0.4324.182}"

Additional Information:

selenium hub: `sudo -u selenium nohup java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role hub -host http://hub_ip:4444 &`

selenium node: `sudo -u selenium nohup java -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -browser browserName=chrome -hub http://hub_ip:4444/grid/register`

Does anyone have any idea what may be going on?

***When I point the application to a server running the standalone selenium I have no problems.

Comment: Why are you referring to hub by `node_ip` (not `hub_ip`) in node configuration?

Comment: Typing failure only

Answer (score 0):

I may not have a full answer for you as I usually don't set the browser name in the node as it can be set though java or python later.

But I assume you are trying to set this node to point to the hub?
This will point the node to look for the hub at the node IP

-hub http://node_ip:4444/grid/register

The Node needs to know where the Hub will be so replace the above with the below.

-hub http://hub_ip:4444/grid/register

Comment: I was wrong when typing, but i fix the post. I tried to climb the node without the browser name but the error remains the same. When I enter the grid console, the nodes are registered correctly.

Comment: In your node definition you use the "standalone.jar" rather than the webdriver jar eg Chromedriver.jar this is not my experience but maybe there is new functionaloty. I would also suggest cutting out the nohup flags until you have it running as vanilla as possible.